# UITableView Showing 2 Cells For Every Item

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

My tableview parses a calendar RSS Feed.  I set up the cell to have a blank calendar icon as the image for every cell, and add subviews for the month and day, which it detects using NSDate from the RSS itself.  However, for some reason, it shows 2 cells for every event, and I cannot figure out why.  Here is the code for the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
    NSString *monthfromdate = [formatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", monthfromdate);
    [formatter release];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd"];
    NSString *datefromdate = [formatter2 stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    NSLog(@"%@", datefromdate);
    [formatter2 release];

    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"01"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"January";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"02"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"February";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"03"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"March";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"04"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"April";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"05"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"May";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"06"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"June";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"07"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"July";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"08"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"August";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"09"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"September";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"10"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"October";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"11"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"November";
    }
    if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"12"]) {
        self.currentmonth = @"December";
    }


    NSString *currentday = datefromdate;


    NSString *articleDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:entry.articleDate];
    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:15];
    UIFont *cellFont2 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:12];
    UIFont *cellFont3 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:9];
    UIFont *cellFont4 = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialRoundedMTBold" size:18];

    UILabel *month = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 10, 53, 21)];
    month.font = cellFont3;
    month.text = currentmonth;
    month.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    month.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UILabel *date = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(11, 21, 50, 45)];
    date.font = cellFont4;
    date.text = currentday;
    date.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    date.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *alternate = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1,1,69,69)];
    alternate.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar1.png"];
    alternate.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    UILabel *alternatelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(82,0,228,53)];

    alternatelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    CALayer * l = [alternate layer];

    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    UILabel *detailLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(82, 20, 228, 53)];
    detailLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    detailLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", articleDateString, entry.blogTitle];
    detailLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    detailLabel.font = cellFont2;
    alternatelabel.font = cellFont;

    alternatelabel.text = entry.articleTitle;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:alternate];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:alternatelabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:detailLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:month];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:date];
    [detailLabel release];
    [alternatelabel release];
    [alternate release];        

}




return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are wrong using cell reusing mechanism.** Use this template

```
#define TAG_MONTH 1001

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
// any other views can be added to cell here

    UILabel *month = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 10, 53, 21)];
    month.font = cellFont3;
    month.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    month.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    month.tag = TAG_MONTH;

}

// here you should fill all fields of cell with "entry" or make it empty
NSString currentmonth = @"something";
UILabel *month = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:TAG_MONTH];
    month.text = currentmonth;


return cell;
}
```

Other moments :

1. you shouldn't init formatter in loop, init it once.
2. Exctract it into new method

   if ([monthfromdate isEqualToString:@"01"]) {
         self.currentmonth = @"January";
     }

   and optimize, it can be simpler

Comment: when I put in all my code outside of the if (cell == nil) brackets, it gets rewritten on everytime I scroll new cell contents in.  Not sure what you meant after your #2 in your answer.

Comment: you should put not all code outside, only part that do setup a cell with model. Part for adding subviews to cell should be in "if"

Comment: I updated a little bit my answer for you better to understand. You should use that way to fill all fields in cell

Comment: I figured out the reason I was getting 2 rows for each event was early on in code I had a duplication adding objects to the NSMutableArray used to populate it.  Cell reusing is still giving me fits though

Answer (score 0):

Check the number this method is returning, may be its returning 2

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

Comment: It returns the count of the array that is used for this.